# SQL Server Management Studio GROUP BY clause SHORTCUT

Tags: t-sql

Is there is a shortcut or tool or something in T-SQL in SQL Server Management Studio that will allow you to automatically create a GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Automatically create how, Mich?  What parts of the clause do you want SSMS to infer?  I suspect regardless of your answer to this, the answer is still going to be "no".

Comment: Copy and paste all of your values which aren't in an aggregation function?

Comment: +1 for "Copy and Paste" - I can't think of any other way to make the task simpler.

Comment: I use RedGate SQL Tools extensively, which automates things like cleaning up SQL (CTRL+B, L).  I'm looking for something to create a GROUP BY clause based on the select statement (GROUP BY values that aren't SUM or MAX or whatever)

Answer (score 5):

I put this as a comment ... but it is actually a solution.

Copy and paste all of your values which aren't in an aggregation function?

Answer (score 1):

I find that the SELECT list contains my GROUP BY columns usually. Or vice versa so I copy, paste. And/or the ORDER BY.

Also, if you drag from Object Explorer Columns node for a table it puts a CSV list of columns in for you. This is a useful shortcut.

This is without using 3rd party tools like SSMS Tools Pack or Red Gate SQL Prompt

Comment: Thanks for the Object Exporer tip! Never knew about that before.